# The number of $2\times 2$ complex matrices satisfying $A^{3}=A$

Tags: linear-algebra

A  is  a $2\times 2$   matrix  with  complex  entries  satisfying  $A^{3}=A$.  How  many  such  $A$'s  are  there?
 The  possible  solutions  of  the  equation  are $0$,$1$,$-1$ .  So  I  thought  any upper  or  lower  triangular  matrix  with  diagonal  entries  any  two  from  the  above  three  numbers  will  satisfy  the  given  equation. And  the  third  number  being  chosen  arbitrarily , there  will be infinitely  many  such  matrices. Now  also  a  triangular  matrix  with  characteristic  polynomial  with  repeated  roots, if  the  minimal polynomial has  only  one  linear  factor  will  also  satisfy this. Then  the  number  is  infinite.

But  are  these  all  the  matrices  that  count  here?  What  other  matrices  $2\times 2$ complex  will  satisfy  $A^{3}=A$ ?
  Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: I think you are asking number upto conjugacy...

Comment: If $A$ is nonsingular then $A^2-I=0$. Such an $A$ is said to be involutory. Here are some involutory matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: If $A^3=A$, then $\det A \in \{ 0, 1, -1\}$. However, $\det A\in \{ 0, 1, -1\}$ is not enough to guarantee that $A^3=A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* The polynomial $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$. What are the possible minimal polynomials of $A$? Since $A$ is merely $2\times2$, one can recover the Jordan form from the minimal polynomial. Therefore, the number of possible minimal polynomials of $A$ is exactly the number of possible choices of $A$ up to similarity.

Comment: So  up to  similarity ,  the  number  is  finite , $6$  in  this  case (  for  minimal  polynomials  $x$,$x-1$.$x+1$,$x(x-1)$,$x(x+1)$,$(x-1)(x+1)$). But  as  the  question  did  not  say  anything  about  similarity  or  as  such ,  so  the  number  will  be  infinite  if  distinct  matrices  are  counted .  Is  that  right?

Comment: @user118494 Yes. In particular, $\pmatrix{1&z\\ 0&-1}$ is a solution for every complex number $z$.

Comment: @user118494 Minimal polynomials cannot be $x, x-1, x+1$ since, Matrix is $2 \times 2$, the polynomial $x(x-1)(x+1)$ is irreducible and minimal polynomial must contain all of its eigenvalues. so, minimal polynomials must be $x(x-1), x(x+1), (x+1)(x-1)$.